# Django template keyword `choice_value` in no longer work in 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

There is a multiple checkbox in template, if value contain in render the choice will checked by default. It works well with 1.10.

form.py:

```
class NewForm(forms.Form):
    project = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
        queryset=Project.objects.filter(enable=True)
    )
```

template:

```
{% for p in form.project %}
<label for="{{ p.id_for_label }}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ p.name }}" id="{{ p.id_for_label }}"
        value="{{ p.choice_value }}"
        {% if p.choice_value|add:"0" in form.project.initial %} checked{% endif %}>
    <p>{{ p.choice_label }}</p>
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def order_start(request, order_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order.end_time = timezone.now()
            order.save()
            order.project = form.cleaned_data['project']
            order.save()
            return HttpResponsec(order.id)
    else:
        form = NewForm(initial={
            'project': [p.pk for p in order.project.all()],
        })

    return render(request, 'orders/start.html', {'form': form, 'order': orderc})
```

When I upgrade to Django 1.11, `{{ p.name }}` and `{{ p.choice_value }}` return nothing. I know 1.11 has removed `choice_value`, but how to solve this problem?

1.10 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/
1.11 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/

Comment: Did you tried `value` instead of `choice_value` ?

Comment: @L_S I tried `value` return nothing.

Comment: You can debug it youself from server side like `dir(form.project[0])`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As @L_S 's comments. I debug with `dir(form)`, all value contained in `form.project.data` here's the correct code:

```
{% for choice in form.project %}
<labelc for="{{ choice.id_for_label }}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ choice.data.name }}" id="{{ choice.id_for_label }}" 
    value="{{ choice.data.value }}"{% if choice.data.selected %} checked{% endif %}>
    {{ choice.data.label }}
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: though already reflected in your solution, it may be worth noting that in django 1.11 the checked attribute rendered by form widgets now uses HTML5 boolean syntax rather than XHTML’s checked='checked'

Comment: finally got it `{{ choice.data.value }}`. thanks, dude! +1

Comment: We ran into this problem when we upgraded from Django 1.9.5 to 2.x, and the same fix worked for us.