# How to get the value of an individual radio button in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way for a template to examine the value of an individual radio button?

I know how to get other attributes:

```
{% for button in myform.radio_select %}
    {{button.tag}}
    {{button.choice_label}}
    {{button.id_for_label}}
{% endfor %}
```

But how do I get the value?  I tried the obvious `{{button.value}}` and the less obvious `{{button.tag.value}}` but they did not work.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675029/django-template-keyword-choice-value-in-no-longer-work-in-1-11) says that as of Django 1.11, the value is stored in `{{button.data.value}}`.

Previous versions of Django used `{{button.choice_value}}`.